# How to deal with static methods in PHP OOP?

Tags: php, oop

I have a super class called `LClass`. Then I create other classes, which extend `LClass`.
For example this are classes for tables in database. ( `user`, `order`, etc...)
In each of these classes I use some `static function getRecordById($id)`, which returns some array. The difference between these functions, they use different table names for executing. I want to put this `static function getRecordById($id)` in `LClass`. The problem is, that function is static, and for this I need some static variables to be set before I do something like `$someUser = user::getRecordById($id)`. 
Or any other suggestions?

Comment: Static is evil. You've proven that.

Comment: Is it better to do `$user = new user;` before `$someUser = user::getRecordById($id);`  ?

Comment: Karimov: yes, much better. According to the last phrases from your question - you need to store some state. That is what object are used for.

Comment: edit, I meant `$user = new user();` I considered, that we can also have `getRecordByName($name)` function. So `$id` in constructor does not always help.

Comment: Actually I am a bit wrong with placing the previous comment :) That was the answer for @Tom.

Comment: Static is NOT evil as such. When applying the OOP paradigma, you really want to avoid static though, because it goes against that paradigma and makes your code really hard to test. On the other hand there are definitely use cases where static makes sense, e.g. toolbox type of classes.

Comment: I decided to use static, because currently I am using Yii framework, where you can get some result of static function without setting any parameters before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programming *exclusively* using static methods is not **object** oriented programming, it's "class oriented" programming. And it's essentially the same as procedural code with a sliver of namespacing. Static methods have their use, but it is limited. Static methods should never do the main work of a class.

Read [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/).

Comment: Yes, but in classes can also be some `not` static functions. In case of saving some records.

Comment: Yes, there can be. There *should* be. If you start instantiating your objects and use non-static methods, *then* you've started practicing OOP.

Comment: @deceze if you make your answer less extreme by providing an example of a situation where static makes sense, I'll not write my own answer! :)

Comment: @markus I have written about that long and hard in the linked article. It's actually very moderate, not extreme at all. :) Changed the answer a bit to reflect that.

Comment: Well, I agree, I try to avoid static... but telling the OP that it's evil may not be the best thing to do. Anyways, your answer is now more balanced for my taste. And nice article, btw.

Comment: @markus I never said at any point it's "evil", nor do I think so. You're mistaking me for zerkms. :)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I confused your name with zerkms in the comment section under the question. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid static methods. As simple as that.

Regarding your comment on the original question, consider the following code example:

```
$user = new User($id);
```